# Pandas to_csv AmbiguousTimeError

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, dst

When exporting a dataframe (pandas version 17.0) with a time zone aware datetime index and daylight saving times, the to_csv method raises an AmbiguousTimeError time error. E.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"c1": np.random.randn(960)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range("2015-10-1", periods=960, freq="H", tz="Europe/Berlin"))
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Leads to an error that daylight savings time cannot be inferred:

> AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2015-10-25 02:00:00'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument

As a workaround I currently convert the index to string before exporting:

```
df.index = df.index.map(str)
```

Is there a way to directly address the issue when calling the to_csv method?

### Update1

```
pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.9.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 8
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.17.0
nose: 1.3.4
pip: 7.1.2
setuptools: 18.3.1
Cython: None
numpy: 1.10.0b1
scipy: 0.14.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
IPython: 3.2.1
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.3.0
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.4
blosc: None
bottleneck: 0.8.0
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.4
matplotlib: 1.4.3
openpyxl: 1.8.6
xlrd: 0.9.3
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: 0.5.7
lxml: 3.3.5
bs4: 4.3.2
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 0.9.7
pymysql: None
psycopg2: 2.5.3 (dt dec pq3 ext)
```

### Update2

As an update to this, it seems that assigning a date range with daylight savings time as DateTimeIndex does not work at all and produces the ambiguous time error:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range("2015-10-25 00:00", "2015-10-25 04:00", freq="H", tz="Europe/Berlin"))
```

Any hints what I am missing?

Comment: Just to finish this, updating to pandas 17.1 both error do not occur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify pandas version. But this is ok in >= 0.14.1

```
In [18]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={"c1": np.random.randn(960)}, 
                  index=pd.date_range("2015-10-1", periods=960, freq="H", tz="Europe/Berlin"))

In [20]: df.to_csv("test.csv")

In [21]: df['20151025':'20151025 05:00:00']
Out[21]: 
                                 c1
2015-10-25 00:00:00+02:00 -0.424467
2015-10-25 01:00:00+02:00  1.118855
2015-10-25 02:00:00+02:00  1.569548
2015-10-25 02:00:00+01:00  1.427732
2015-10-25 03:00:00+01:00 -1.371838
2015-10-25 04:00:00+01:00 -0.266418
2015-10-25 05:00:00+01:00  0.779215

In [22]: !head -585 test.csv|tail -10
2015-10-24 22:00:00+02:00,-1.53089210839
2015-10-24 23:00:00+02:00,0.801888214216
2015-10-25 00:00:00+02:00,-0.424466712863
2015-10-25 01:00:00+02:00,1.11885497214
2015-10-25 02:00:00+02:00,1.56954806458
2015-10-25 02:00:00+01:00,1.42773177107
2015-10-25 03:00:00+01:00,-1.37183787312
2015-10-25 04:00:00+01:00,-0.266417892642
2015-10-25 05:00:00+01:00,0.779214565214
2015-10-25 06:00:00+01:00,-0.102814294685
```

Comment: The version is 17.0 (edited question). I tried it under 15.0 and the error does not occur. Under 17.0 it does.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have updated the post and also added another example raising the same error. If you could have a look and let me know wether I am missing something, I would be very happy.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. Once with indexing

pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2012-10-28 02:00:00'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument

I had to change

```
data['time'] = date
data.set_index('time')
```

to this:

```
data['time'] = date
data.index = date
```

--> Solved

And in the same go with pd.to_csv() I got this error:

pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2012-10-28 02:00:00'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument

Solved the problem by downgrading pandas with:

```
pip install pandas==0.16.2
```